# Uploading multiple files with Json data using Volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley

Hi I have to upload multiple files with one Json parameter having multiple data. **I have worked on single file upload with Json Params using volley**. I **tried this lot of time** but no luck so finally posting here. For your reference the request will be similar to

```
{
 "name": "Thomas",
 "email": "thomas@xyz.com",
 "dob": "13/05/1975",
 "fileArray": [{
  "profileImage": "thomas.png",
  "Comments": "My first birthday"
 }]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: upload multiple files. the files should be added like "fileArray": [{
  "profileImage": "thomas.png",
  "Comments": "My first birthday"
 }]

Comment: "upload multiple files", how is that a question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
"fileArray": [{
  "profileImage": "thomas1.png",
  "Comments": "My first birthday"
 },
{
  "profileImage": "thomas2.png",
  "Comments": "My second birthday"
 },
{
  "profileImage": "thomas3.png",
  "Comments": "My third birthday"
 }]
```

is what you are looking for?

Comment: yes Christine, exactly like this with some other params like name": "Thomas",
 "email": "thomas@xyz.com",
 "dob": "13/05/1975",